Auto-follow a staging ground post after publishing
Currently there is an option to auto-upvote after publishing:

Can an analogous auto-follow option be added as well, e.g., "Follow when posted on main site"?

an additional "tier" would be to have a setting to control default state of that checkbox

agreed -- either a static default, or a dynamic "remember previous state" setting

Maybe it could also be instead of auto upvoting content that might have been edited in the mean time. I get the idea but with a notification after publishing one would be able to review the decision.
